# Is it correct and natural to say "come on the time you do something" when you really want someone to do something?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *come on the time you do something* when you really want someone to do something? For example:

> **Come on the time you come** and we go on a trip together.

If it's not something a native English speaker would  say, then what would they say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is a literal translation of an expression in your language.  It doesn't make any sense in English.  If I heard it I'd probably assume it means "Come whenever you feel like it" (Come at the time you were going to come anyway even if I didn't ask you to come)

There are lots of ways to say that you really want someone to do something.

> I really want to go on a trip together with you.

But I could probably think of 50 or more ways to say something like this.